# Run exe registered in path remotely with powershell

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I've got a ps script that runs on an remote computer (during a TFS build, the script runs on one of the build agents). I'm trying to call an exe that is contained in a folder which is registered in the PATH env variable. However when I make a call to the exe, without the full path - as I'd expect to be able to since it's registered in PATH - powershell throws an error stating

> tf : The term 'tf' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
>    file, or operable program

Does powershell know about the PATH environment variable when running a powershell script remotely?

Comment: It looks like the error is in your PowerShell script so can you please share it?

Comment: Do you have remote `$env:Path` populated? It might be you're running a remote Powershell session without loaded user profile.

Comment: I don't think the script is the problem as I've run the command whilst in the powershell ISE and it works fine. Here's the line of code anyway             `gci -Path $AGENT_MODEL_DIR -Filter *.cs | ForEach-Object { tf history $_ }` where $AGENT_MODEL_DIR is a directory path

Comment: vesper, I'm not sure, how would I set the remote $env:path variable

Comment: Use "@" before the user name for them to be notified of the comment. I also wonder, does remote workstation have `tf.exe` available in its path. Also please post code on how do you initiate remote Powershell session.

Comment: @Vesper tf.exe is available in the remote machine's path yes. I don't initiate a remote connection, during a team foundation build process, the powershell script is simply invoked on the remote machine

Comment: Consider dumping the `dir env:` output from under the scheduled task content, as well as `$env:path`, probably the user's path is either empty or lacks the folder with `ts.exe`.

Comment: @vesper I did a dump of $env:path and it does indeed lack the folder I added to the system environment variable. I wasn't aware the path varied for each user?

Comment: A stupid solution: `if ($env:path -notmatch "c:\path\to\tf") {$env:path="c:\path\to\tf;$env:path"} ` Just check if a folder is in path, if not, add.

Comment: Is this really a remoting scenario?  Or is it just the case that TeamBuild gets the script as part of getting the workspace and then executes the script on the build machine? Be aware, that when TeamBuild runs on a machine it runs under whatever account has been configured for the TeamBuild service.  You need to make sure the PATH env has been set for that account.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PATH environment variable is set for the account that the `Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host` service is configured to use.  Or, what I would do is use a path like this:

```
& $env:VS120COMNTOOLS\..\ide\tf.exe
```

The VS120COMNTOOLS env var should be defined for all accounts.

Comment: I think you were right in your comment, my description was misleading as this is not really a remoting scenario. I was not aware that a system variable could be different for different users.